# Micronaut blocking declarative http client

Tags: micronaut

By default [declarative http client](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation) in Micronaut is reactive (async) and working with task pool and multiple threads.

In my case I need to have a full control for execution flow and prefer to work with blocking (non-reactive) http client.

Is any possibility to make declarative http client blocked?

Comment: what do you mean by full control?

Comment: "Is any possibility to make declarative http client blocked?" - If your abstract method in your `@Client` interface declares that it returns a non-reactive type, does the client block?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have usual String return type. But a calls done via thread pool. At result via fork-join the code waiting for responce, but looking for simple execution in the same thread

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the Micronaut HttpClient is reactive and it uses implementation of `io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient` under the hood (see also `io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice`).

Therefore it is not possible to use a non reactive Micronaut http client but you can always choose another Java http client library.

But I'm curious. What do you mean by

> In my case I need to have a full control for execution flow

With this context the answer could maybe be a bit more precise.

Comment: Initial problem was connected with proxy selector. I have tried to stick proxy to crowler "session" by thread local, but got an issue because of multi threading. Probably I will use another implementatin of http client.